# How to update two column at same time?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, colors

My SQLite Database has 5 columns and I want to update the  datas.

It was created first time, only I have to update one column that it works. But now I  realize that I have to update 2 columns. My application has a customized listview and it has been created by these 4 columns(except id column).

I must update 2 columns. They are third column and  Fourth column. First, in my created database I have to update third column that I can find by id from my database. But now, I tried to update third column  and Fourth column. I do this because fourth column is integer of color that I want to update color my listview according to  third column value.

I am looking my answer but I did not find.How can I fix it ?

My database add method;

```
public boolean addData(String item , String number   ) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL2, item);
        contentValues.put(COL3 , number);
        contentValues.put(COL4, "50" ); //third column
        contentValues.put(COL5 , "#27fbf0"); // Fourth column
        Log.d(TAG, "addData: Adding " + item + " to " + TABLE_NAME);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

My database update method;

```
  public void updateName(String newName, int id, String oldName,String newboya,String oldboya){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " +
                COL4 + " = '" + newName +  "' AND " +
                COL5 + " = '" + newboya+  "' WHERE " +
                COL1 + " = '" + id + "'" + " AND " +
                COL4  + " = '" + oldName + " AND " +  //third column
                COL5 + " = '" + oldboya+ "'"; // Fourth column
        Log.d(TAG, "updateName: query: " + query);
        Log.d(TAG, "updateName: Setting name to " + newName);
        db.execSQL(query);
    }
How to I create my customized listview ;

    while(data.moveToNext()){

            listDataId.add(data.getString(0));

            listData.add(data.getString(1));


            listDatanumber.add(data.getString(2));

            listDataoran.add(data.getString(3));
listDataBoya.add(data.getString(4));



        }
        liste.setAdapter(oyunTextView);

    }


    class OyunTextView extends BaseAdapter {


        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return  listData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return listData.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.oyuntextview, null);
            TextView namesbox = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.isim);
            sayılar = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sayı);
            namesbox.setText(listData.get(position));
            sayılar.setText(listDataoran.get(position));

           convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(listDataBoya.get(position)));


            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

How to color set to database with new value; sonuc is new value.It goes to COL4

```
                       sonuc = Integer.valueOf(old) + toplamaislemi;


                    if (sonuc >= 10 && sonuc < 19){ //20-10
                        boyayazı =   "#032E28" ;
                    }
                                //

                    if (sonuc <0 || sonuc ==0 ){
                        sonuc = 0;
                        boyayazı = "#121210";
   Toast.makeText(AnaMenu.this,
           "Bu kişi için en düşük orana ulaştınız.Artık bu kişi ile eşleştirilmeyeceksiniz.",
           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
              int se = Integer.parseInt(listDataId.get(selec));
             String oldboya = listDataBoya.get(selec);



                 mDatabaseHelper.updateName(String.valueOf(sonuc), se, old ,boyayazı , oldboya  );

                     oyunTextView.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Intent diger = new Intent(AnaMenu.this,AnaMenubos.class);
                    startActivity(diger);
AnaMenu.this.finish();



                }
            }  )             .show();


        }
```

My logcat :

```
08-10 04:55:00.681 791-791/com.example.asusnb.myapplication D/DatabaseHelper: updateName: query: UPDATE people_table SET oran = '45' AND boya = '#139F98' WHERE ID = '13' AND oran = '50 AND boya = '#27fbf0'
08-10 04:55:00.681 791-791/com.example.asusnb.myapplication D/DatabaseHelper: updateName: Setting name to 45
08-10 04:55:00.681 791-791/com.example.asusnb.myapplication E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "#27fbf0": syntax error
08-10 04:55:00.681 791-791/com.example.asusnb.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-10 04:55:00.691 791-791/com.example.asusnb.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.asusnb.myapplication, PID: 791
                                                                              android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "#27fbf0": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE people_table SET oran = '45' AND boya = '#139F98' WHERE ID = '13' AND oran = '50 AND boya = '#27fbf0'
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1093)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:670)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1795)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1726)
                                                                                  at com.example.asusnb.myapplication.DatabaseHelper.updateName(DatabaseHelper.java:106)
                                                                                  at com.example.asusnb.myapplication.AnaMenu$2.onClick(AnaMenu.java:299)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:161)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: Please cleanup your code, and also consider using prepared statements.

Comment: off course.I am doing now

Comment: I have editted  prepared statements. Where is the code that clean up ?It is my application code or at my question.

Comment: You are missing a quote... `AND oran = '50 AND boya = '#27fbf0'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code snippet for updating your database. Parameters are self explained.

```
public String update(String table, ContentValues data, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDB();
    //String where = "id=?";
    //String[] whereArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(id)};
    try {
        long returnId = db.update(table, data, where, whereArgs);
        if (returnId > 0) {
            db.close();
            return "Success";
        } else {
            db.close();
            return "fail";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String error = e.getMessage().toString();
        db.close();
        return error;
    }
}
```

Calling can be done like this way. productDetailsContentValues are the column names with associated values( The values you want to update in this case ). "where" is the pointer of the database row. Here we are selecting the row with id (which is supposed to be unique). Then we are checking if the row exists by counting record. if the row exists, we are updating with the content values in the table.

```
ContentValues productDetailsContentValues = new ContentValues();
 productDetailsContentValues.put("barcode", aProduct.getProduct().getBarcode());
 productDetailsContentValues.put("code", aProduct.getProduct().getCode());

String where = " id = " + aProduct.getProduct().getId();
if (databaseHelper.recordCount(DatabaseInfo.DATABASE_TABLE_PRODUCT, where) > 0) {
     databaseHelper.update(DatabaseInfo.DATABASE_TABLE_PRODUCT, productDetailsContentValues, where, null);
  } else {
     long id = databaseHelper.insert(DatabaseInfo.DATABASE_TABLE_PRODUCT, productDetailsContentValues);
}
```

Comment: I don"t understand second part. I am beginner at database.Can you explain it ?

Comment: I have edited and explained . Please check the description above the second part.

Comment: I get it. :)Thanks for helping.